# How post may return proper get from its method?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I want to create a trivial site with *ClassBasedView* proof of concept in mind. However I found it hard to interact between **get** and **post** methods. So I have the following view.py:

```
# View.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import MyClass


class MyClass(ListView):

    model = Users

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        users = Users.objects.count()
        context = {'users': users, 'userform': UserForm}
        return render(request, 'mysite/index.html', context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.POST.get('create_user', False):
            new_user = UserForm(data=request.POST)
            if new_user.is_valid():
                new_user.save()
            return super(MyClass, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
            # return redirect('/mysite/')
        else:
            return super(MyClass, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
            # return redirect('/mysite/')
```

The code doesn't work. Nevertheless commented **redirect**s do the trick. But that doesn't allow me to pass arguments. Actually I can't find a good way to do it in *ClassBasedView* concept. Googling for few hours made me more confused.

**Update**, error code:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /userbase/

userbase/users_list.html

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/userbase/
Django Version:     1.8.1
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    userbase/users_list.html   
Exception Location:     /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in select_template, line 76
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python2.7
Python Version:     2.7.9
```

Comment: I think list view is for listing objects, not saving them...try FormView or something. Also, there are several methods you can override apart from get and post. You can find more info on that here: https://ccbv.co.uk/  
Remember that specific class based views are good for something, trying to force them to make something different that what they were designed for may be a headache...use a more general view instead and code the behaviour for that instead if you need it (View, TemplateView).

Comment: Check get_context_data

Comment: Thanks, you mean class based views aren't good for get/post methods or what you're trying to say?

Comment: If I have 5 chocolate bars, how fast does my car go? "The code doesn't work" tells us exactly nothing about your actual problem. If you want help, please state what the actual problem is. (Answer: I don't have a car.)

Comment: I want to use get method within post method. Or you want me to add a error output of broken code? Well, I don't think it will be helpful enough, but if you suggest I may to put it above.

Comment: The error message will most likely enable me to help you. I did the same thing yesterday at work.

Comment: What i am trying to say is, understand first the more general views so you can understand how they work.

Comment: The error message is exactly what we need. It might not contain _all_ the information we need, but it's a starting point, and often it's enough.

Comment: Okay, I've updated the error code. As you see It's looking for non-existent file, my code doesn't generate users_list.html anywhere, so it's somewhere in django.

Answer (score 0):

I made a sample project [here](https://github.com/arpheno/ReverseForeignKeyFilterExample/blob/master/reversefk/views.py), which performs as requested by you. The parts of your code relevant to the question work as intended. The error must be somewhere else.

I have tested the linked project and it returns the get response upon posting data via a submit button.